# How to open a picture in gallery

Tags: android, eclipse, android-intent, image-gallery

I want to open a picture in a gallery. Gallery path is    root + "/saved_images" and its name is fname. It opens gallery that I can choose that picture, but I want to open directly that picture.

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString();
String fname = "Image-" + formattedDate + ".jpg";

Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(root + "/saved_images"+fname), "image/*");
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Do you have the Read External Storage permission? http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html#READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES).toString()` returns you something in the form of `"/storage/emulated/0/Pictures"`.

To have a valid `Uri`, it just misses `"file://"` in front of your file path.

Additionally, if `"saved_images"` is a directory, you are missing a `/` between the directory name and your filename.

**All together**,

```
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + root + "/saved_images/" + fname), "image/*");
```

should do the job.

Answer (score 1):

You need to add file:// to the path, like this:
intent.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file://" + root + "/saved_images/"+fname), "image/*");